# Ng2-smart-table cell background color depending on content

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table

I'm using the module Ng2-smart-table (https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation).

Is it possible to customize the background of a cell / or entire row depending of the content of the same cell / or a cell of the same row? Can you provide an example?

Thank you

Comment: As per documentation they are not accepting any `style/CSS` as input from user, so might be the case you have to define forcefully style

Comment: I supouse you always can configure your comlumn type html, and feed the data with a html,e.g. "<span style='color:red'>Hello</span>", and not simple "Hello", but I'm not sure

Comment: Is not better to use the renderComponent? https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/tree/master/src/app/pages/examples/custom-edit-view  However I tried the basic example but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewCell } from 'ng2-smart-table';


@Component({
  template: `
  <span [ngClass]="classToApply">{{renderValue}}</span>
  `,
  styles: ['.error { color: red; }']
})
export class MyColumnRenderComponent implements ViewCell, OnInit {

  renderValue: string;

  @Input() value: string | number;
  @Input() rowData: any;

  classToApply = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.value == 'MY_ERROR_CODE') {
      this.classToApply = 'error';
    }
    this.renderValue = this.value.toString().toUpperCase();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a style with a dynamic variable. In my case, I needed to apply background based on the type of fuel so I use as follows

```
 Volume: {
    type: 'html',
    title: 'Volume',
    valuePrepareFunction: ((Volume, row)=> {
        return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<h6 class="text-white p-t-0 qlz-line-height text-center" style="background:${this.getFuelColor(row.FuelType)}"><strong>${Volume} gal </strong> </h6>`);
    }),
    width: '15%'
  }
```

And in getFuelColor(fuelType) I am derving color based on fuelType.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to change the class based on a cell value, there is **valuePrepareFunction** :

```
valuePrepareFunction: (cell) => {
  if (cell === 'one') {
    return '<p class="firstCellClass">' + cell + '</p>';
  } else if (row.anotherCellName == 'two') {
    return '<p class="secondCellClass">' + cell + '</p>';
  } else {
    return '<p class="defaultCellClass">' + cell + '</p>';
  }
},
```

---

There also is a **rowClassFunction**, for the entire row too:

https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/pull/355

---

The custom render component can be usefull when you want to inject specific css style that is not rendered within a 'html' cell type.